# independence of random variables depends on the probability measure chosen

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm currently working on the book *A course in probability theory* by Kai Lai Chung and encountered a problem: (exercise 3.3.1 on page 65, 3rd edition)

> Show that two r.v.'s on ($\Omega, \mathcal{F}$) may be independent according to one p.m. $\mathcal{P}$ but not according to another.

Here r.v. stands for random variable and p.m. for probability measure.

In my several attempts, I first tried to construct some simple discrete ones, say, the probability space $\Omega$ is finite. But I even failed to construct two independent r.v.'s other than trivial ones.

I then turned to a given ($\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P}$) where the independence of r.v. $X_1,X_2$ holds, and tries to construct another p.m. $\mathcal{\tilde{P}}$ based on $\mathcal{P}$, where the independence may fail. But any of the construction seemed to fail the axioms that a p.m. needs to meet.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Take two random variables which both take two values $\{a,b\}\,.$ Do you see that the following joint distribution
\begin{align} && a && b\\\hline a&&p^2&&pq\\b&&pq&&q^2\end{align}
makes them independent? Next step: take four other probabilities in the table and check if independence still holds.

Comment: Any two random variables are independent w.r.t. a degenerate probability measure.

Comment: Thank you both! Now I've figured it out clearly. A stupid question XD